# Changes to a page in selenium in java, how to refresh the page to load the modifications

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I have a driver in java selenium :

```
driver.get(url);
```

I have made some changes to the page with this method :

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+element.getText()+"';", element);
```

How do I reload the page with the modifications ?
I have tried driver.navigate.refresh() but that doesn't work.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: It's not the best way to assign value property. Can you assign it via action with input directly? 
Smth like `input.sendKeys(value)?`

Comment: Actually, if you assign input value, it would work, but without submitting it, after refresh default value would be shown.

Comment: The element in question is a <a href/> tag.

Comment: I want to erase it if a certain condition is met

Comment: Why would you extract the textContext and set it as the value to the _`value`_ attribute? What is your usecase?

Comment: After the is made you just need to create a new instance of the element and test the changes on this new instance.

Comment: That's an error the line is

Comment: jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='';", element);